# What is an "inference kernel"?

Tags: terminology, large-language-models, chatgpt, inference

In the recent event where ChatGPT "went crazy", this term was used in the official post-mortem to describe what happened:

> In this case, the bug was in the step where the model chooses these numbers. Akin to being lost in translation, the model chose slightly wrong numbers, which produced word sequences that made no sense. More technically, **inference kernels** produced incorrect results when used in certain GPU configurations.

Now I know what **inference** is, at least wrt LLMs. It's when you use a trained LLM to generate text by giving it a prompt (feel free to offer a more technical clarification if necessary). As for **kernel** that has several meanings in computing generally, such as an [operating system kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) being the core part of the **OS**, often in contrast to shells, including command lines and GUIs. Then there is the [sense of kernel in image processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)), also known as a **convolution matrix**. There's also **Compute Kernels** in **GPGPU** programming, with which I am the least familiar.

But what does the overall phrase "inference kernel" refer to technically? My hunch is that it's some kind of specialization of the GPU sense, though I read [a comment in an AI-adjacent forum](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/koNsuop5AHxBG5D7t/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-went-wrong-with-chatgpt?commentId=5ts6boALcsvFHS9Ba) that it's related to the OS sense, which I doubt is accurate.

Other than that I can't actually find this term mentioned very much, and I can't find it defined at all.

---

**EDIT**

[I found a definition of *inference kernel*](http://www.proof-technologies.com/misc/glossary.html) but it's about automatic theorom provers and doesn't seem to be applicable to AI, not that I can follow it very well:

> **inference kernel** : (n) The part of an LCF-style system that implements the deductive system of its formal logic, and relied upon by all subsequent deductive functionality for its soundness. It defines the datatype for internal theorems as an abstract datatype, with the primitive inference rules and the primitive assertion commands as its only primitive constructors. The inference kernel is a crucial trusted component of its system. See "language kernel", "logical core", "core system".

Answer (score 1):

Given the context and [similar usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=inference%20kernel%20site%3Aopenai.com), they're probably referring to compute kernels in GPUs. [This OpenAI blog post](https://openai.com/research/triton) seems informative for more on this topic.